# Foreign key is defined as data annotation but still returning null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I was trying to join tables in `Blazor` Pages as I always used to do in Laravel Eloquent but somehow that was unable to worked out with different data types of FK relationship but now I have made the datatype same and then used data annotation to define foreign but still that property has no row of the table model I mentioned.

My code for `tblEmployees` -

```cs
public partial class TblEmployee
{
    public TblEmployee()
    {
        Employeefrcs = new HashSet<Employeefrc>();
        TblEmployeeDesignations = new HashSet<TblEmployeeDesignation>();
    }

    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }

    // ... irrelevant properties ...

    [ForeignKey("Designation_Code")]
    public TblDesignation Designation { get; set; }

    public virtual TblDepartment DepartmentCodeNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employeefrc> Employeefrcs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblEmployeeDesignation> TblEmployeeDesignations { get; set; }
}
```

and my code for `tblDesignations` -

```cs
public partial class TblDesignation
{
    public TblDesignation()
    {
        TblEmployeeDesignations = new HashSet<TblEmployeeDesignation>();
        TblTeacherWorkLoads = new HashSet<TblTeacherWorkLoad>();
    }

    public int DesignationCode { get; set; }

    // ... irrelevant properties ...    

    public IEnumerable<TblEmployee> TblEmployees { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblEmployeeDesignation> TblEmployeeDesignations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblTeacherWorkLoad> TblTeacherWorkLoads { get; set; }
}
```

and my code for retrieval of model like -

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Cnic</th>
        <th scope="col">Phone</th>
        <th scope="col">Designation</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @{int i = 1}
    @foreach (var employee in employees ?? new List<TblEmployee>())
    {
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">@i</th>
            <td>@employee.EmployeeName</td>
            <td>@employee.CnicNo</td>
            <td>@employee.CellNo</td>
            <td>@(employee.Designation?.DesignationName ?? "Nandla")</td>
            @{i++}
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My model builder has following configurations -

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<TblEmployee>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.EmployeeCode).HasName("PK_dbo.tblEmployees");
    entity.ToTable("tblEmployees");
    entity.HasIndex(e => e.DepartmentCode, "IX_Department_Code");
    
    // ... irrelevant properties configuration ...  

    entity.HasOne(d => d.DepartmentCodeNavigation)
        .WithMany(p => p.TblEmployees)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentCode)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.tblEmployees_dbo.tblDepartment_Department_Code");
});
```

My `tbldesignation` in model builder is -

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<TblDesignation>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.DesignationCode).HasName("PK_dbo.tblDesignations");
    entity.ToTable("tblDesignations");
    
    // ... irrelevant properties configuration ...  
});
```

Comment: @viveknuna thanks for help but this is causing me this error https://prnt.sc/10cmank

Comment: Is this code-first, or database-first?

Comment: @atiyar I have used ef tools to scaffold my existing database

Comment: That `[ForeignKey("Designation_Code")]` annotation, did you add that yourself, or it was generated by the scaffolding? Also, in your configuration, I don't see any code generated for the relationship between `TblEmployee` and `TblDesignation`, which means your existing database didn't have the relation defined.

Comment: Yes actually that relations is defined there but I had to add this manually.

Comment: In your `tblEmployees` configuration code you can see the that defines the relationship between `tblEmployees` and `TblDepartment` entities. But there is no such code defining the relationship between `tblEmployees` and `TblDesignation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just DataAnnotations. Other properties removed for brevity.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class TblEmployee
{
    public int DesignationCode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(DesignationCode))]
    public TblDesignation Designation { get; set; }
}
```

```
public partial class TblDesignation
{
    [Key]
    public int DesignationCode { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(TblEmployee.Designation))]
    public IEnumerable<TblEmployee> TblEmployees { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: After defining this it's giving error https://prnt.sc/10cmank

Comment: Remove the builder code. You are defining it twice

Comment: Thanks for help and now i was missing is when calling paginatedlist i was missing .include method and yes i recreated all the models after modifying database with relations it's now working but still i don't get behind the scene can you please let me know is dataannotation is enough or fluent api is required to define the same realtion over ?

Comment: Now we are getting into opinions. It really depends on the complexity of the models. However I use Annotations as it doesn't obscure the relationship in another file.

Comment: yes you are right but i was thinking both are needed. Now i am clear in all ways. That we can do same things in multiple not multiple steps are important. Let me check your answer way as well so i can accept and can help others as well. Thanks for your time